# Database is read-only

Tags: sql-server

I got this error. How can I resolve it?

> *Failed to update database "msdb" because the database is read-only.
>
>   Could not insert a backup or restore history/detail record in the msdb database. This may indicate a problem with the msdb database. The backup/restore operation was still successful.
>
>   Processed 184 pages for database 'BakupDB', file 'BakupDB' on file 1.
>
>   Processed 2 pages for database 'BakupDB', file 'BakupDB_log' on file 1.*

Sorry for the bad question.

I also get this error:

> *Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\geert\Desktop\C#proj\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF". Operating system error 32: "32 (failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)". Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\geert\Desktop\C#proj\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF' as database 'ASPNETDB'.*

This is my DB:

[image]

Comment: These are two separate questions. Please separate them into two questions.

Answer (score 3):

The backup program is trying to update msdb database but cannot because either the database has only read permissions or the user running the program does not have permissions to write to the database.

Comment: I got another error see question

Comment: `ASPNETDB.MDF` should be included using VisualStudio.

Comment: ASPNETDB.MDF is included I think so

Comment: It's not in the expected location then `C:\Users\geert\Desktop\C#proj\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF`

Comment: how can I see or that the expected location is ?

Comment: try running `aspnet_reqsql -W`